# TEXT File parsing Java

Tags: java, parsing

I've got a text-file which looks like a XML file but it is not a valid XML file. 
How can I parse it? I am using Java.
I need the content of last tag.

Example file:

```
<h4 class="is24qa-objektbeschreibung-label padding-top-xl margin-bottom-              s">Objektbeschreibung</h4> 
<div class="is24-text margin-bottom"> 
<pre class="is24qa-objektbeschreibung">TEST TEST TEST </pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jsoup this way.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line;
        String cline = "";
        Document doc;
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                cline = line;
            }

            doc = Jsoup.parse(cline);
            Elements elements = doc.select("body").first().children();
            for (Element el : elements)
                System.out.println("content: " + el.text());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**input.txt**

```
<h4 class="is24qa-objektbeschreibung-label padding-top-xl margin-bottom-              s">Objektbeschreibung</h4>
<div class="is24-text margin-bottom">
<pre class="is24qa-objektbeschreibung">TEST TEST TEST </pre>
```

Output

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -
content: TEST TEST TEST

Process finished with exit code 0
```